# Declaring and defining angular main module

Tags: angularjs

Learning through reading the [angular tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) under Model and Controller, The first paragraph under the code block app/js/controllers.js.

> Notice that our ng-app directive (on the html tag) now specifies/declares the phonecatApp module name as the module to load when bootstrapping the Angular application.

And the first line of code in the controllers.js is:
`var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);`

I have been struggling to understand what exactly this line of code is supposed to do?
And if my understanding serves me right, I have also seen it, where the variable name is omitted as in:

```
    angular.module('phonecatApp', [])
    .controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.phones = [...
```

So the `ng-app="phonecatApp"` tells the script the name of the Angular module to load.
How does the script know about the main angular module definition? is
 `var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);`
a 2 step line, defining the main module and assigning it to a variable?
And if so, can this definition be modified later by adding more controllers/services to it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular.module('phonecatApp', [])
```

defines and registers a module named `phonecatApp`. It's the main module not because it's declared this way, but because that's the module used in `ng-app="phonecatApp"`.

> can this definition be modified later by adding more controllers/services to it

Yes, of course. Adding a controller is done by calling the controller() method of the module. And you can get a reference to the module by calling

```
angular.module('phonecatApp')
```

i.e. the same function as for defining it, but without an array of modules as second argument.

This is documented: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module:

> The angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules. All modules (angular core or 3rd party) that should be available to an application must be registered using this mechanism.
>
> Passing one argument retrieves an existing angular.Module, whereas passing more than one argument creates a new angular.Module

Comment: So var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []); defines the main module and assigning that module to a variable phonecatApp? Is that correct?

Comment: No. It defines **a** module, and assigns that module to a variable. The "main" module is the one used in `ng-app`. It could be that one, or another one. All modules, main or not, are defined the same way.